# How to initiate audio recording when user speaks on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry-10, audio-recording

Hi I am trying to build an application for Blackberry z10 that start recording an audio automatically when user speaks. Like talking tom. Cannot find any information on the web.

Any advice and guidance would be appreciated.